# NGINX + Docker + Google Cloud Compute Engine error - [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy my docker container running Next.js and NGINX to Google Compute Engine. It works perfectly when deployed on local with `docker-compose up` but when deployed to CE I get the error

`[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "nextjs:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4`

The logs on local are

```
Attaching to nextjs, profiles-fe_nginx_1
nextjs    | 2019-05-02T03:51:26: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
nextjs    | 2019-05-02T03:51:26: PM2 log: App [npm:0] starting in -fork mode-
nextjs    | 2019-05-02T03:51:26: PM2 log: App [npm:0] online
nextjs    | > create-next-example-app@ start /usr/app
nextjs    | > NODE_ENV=production node server.js
nextjs    | > Ready on http://localhost:3000
```

**Deployment to CE commands**

`docker-compose build`

`docker tag <local_container> <remote_container>`

`docker push <remove_container`

`gcloud beta compute --project=<project_name> instances create-with-container <instance_name> --zone=europe-west2-c --machine-type=g1-small --container-image=<remove_container>  --tags http-server,https-server`

**`default.conf`**

```
upstream app {
  server nextjs:3000;
}


server {
  listen 80;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  # BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
  # Browser cache - max cache headers from Next.js as build id in url
  # Server cache - valid forever (cleared after cache "inactive" period)
  location /_next/static {
    # proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  # STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
  # Browser cache - "no-cache" headers from Next.js as no build id in url
  # Server cache - refresh regularly in case of changes
  location /static {
    # proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  # DYNAMIC ASSETS - NO CACHE
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
}
```

**`docker-compose` file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    container_name: nextjs
    restart: unless-stopped
  nginx: 
    build: ./nginx
    depends_on:
        - nextjs
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - nextjs:nextjs
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**`./nginx/Dockerfile`**

```
FROM nginx

# Remove any existing config files
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Copy config files
# *.conf files in "conf.d/" dir get included in main config
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80
```

**`./Dockerfile`**

```
FROM node:11.14.0-alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install --global pm2

# Copy "package.json" and "package-lock.json" before other files
# Utilise Docker cache to save re-installing dependencies if unchanged
COPY ./package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --save

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

# Build app
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

# Launch app with PM2
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

Comment: Does `nextjs` show up as the upstream Docker container when you run `docker network inspect <your network>`?

Comment: You have 2 containers, so you have to deploy 2 containers as well